# Apple Watch not found by Xcode

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, xcode11

My Apple Watch is registered under iOS Devices. I can see the UDID. The watch has watchOS 6.11 installed and my iPhone 6 has iOS 13.3 installed. The iPhone pairs just fine with the watch and I can install apps.

In Xcode in Window > Devices and Simulators the watch UDID appears to be set but the Watch name is set to null and the model to Unknown(see image below). This happened after I upgraded Xcode to 11.3.1. Before the upgrade, everything worked fine. I haven't gotten the "trust this computer" popup on the watch after the upgrade but gotten it multiple times on the iPhone. The iPhone build works fine and I can use the app on the phone without problems

[image]

I've tried:

- Unpairing the watch and repairing (twice)
- Updating the watch to firmware 6.11
- Restarting watch, phone and mac multiple times
- Deleted Watch OS Support files from Xcode folder which was reported to fix a similar problem in other Stackoverflow question threads
- Setting the right provisioning profiles for the iOS app and the watch app extension

Anyone experienced anything similar?

Comment: I've experienced this on and off through various versions of Xcode. Filed it in Feedback Assistant (FB5421157), but no response from Apple. If others who experience this bug could also file it with logs that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying everything mentioned above, there was a small update available on the Phone. Weirdly enough, the watch appeared again in Xcode after updating the phone.